# Odroid GPIO pins in ROS without sudo access

Tags: python, ros, gpio, odroid, wiringpi

`Odroid` running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I have `wiringPi2` installed for accessing the GPIO pins. I am able to use the GPIO pins through a Python script, but they require `sudo` access. I have a ROS node (written in Python) in which I want to access the GPIO pin data and publish to a topic. But, I am not able to do so, because wiringPi2 required `sudo` access, and ROS is not defined in root.

I have tried using `wiringPiSetupSys()` function which does not require `sudo` access, but that does not work i.e. I am not able to get the GPIO pin data without `sudo` access.

All the solutions to similar problems for Raspberry Pi platform don't seem to work for Odroid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find a fix to the problem with the exact specifications mentioned. However, when I tested the same code on a Raspberry Pi 3 with `Raspbian`, it works correctly.

So, I have concluded that the issue lies in the OS used i.e. Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

So, a solution might be to use `Raspbian` on `Odroid` itself. I am yet to test whether that works out.

Update : `Raspbian` doesn't exist as such for `Odroid`, so some other work around might be required.